# Java Constructer calling by supper() key word make conflict results

Tags: java

Here is the code I implemented to check behaviors of inheritors

Super class

```
class Vehicle {

    public Vehicle(int x) {
        System.err.println("super param " +x);
    }

    public Vehicle() {
        System.err.println("super defult");
    }
}
```

Sub class

```
class Bus extends Vehicle {

    public Bus(int y) {
        super(y);
        System.out.println("Sub param");
    }

    public Bus() {
        super(11);
        System.out.println("Sub Class defult");
    }
}
```

Main class is

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Bus();
    }
}
```

Three deferent out come results given like below

> **result 1**

[image]

> **result 2**

[image]

> **result 3**

[image]

**What happen in here? The order of the output is different than we expect **

Comment: It looks like you are just getting interference between writing to/flushing of the out and err streams. Pick one, write all messages to it.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The color of the output? The order of the output?

Comment: You are using two different output streams - they flush separately and without a defined order.

Comment: @FinnEggers  The order of the output

Comment: @wthamira that’s because you use two different streams. Programming something runs very fast. So is adding something to a stream. If you use one, they are perfectly ordered. If you use two, one might need longer to process than the other one. That’s it. Only because you put objectA into streamA before you put objectB into streamB does not mean that pbkectA will leave the streamA before objectB does.

Comment: @FinnEggers Thank you. can you put it as a answer. I can accept this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.out is "standard output" (stdout) and System.err is "error output" (stderr), And they both are different file descripters.
Derived class is using stdout fd and Parent class is using stderr fd.

Your program is not forcibly flushing the outputs too. You can force the flush by adding new lines in the statements, and it will preserve the order of prints.

Since your code in not force flushing the outputs on fds, kernel does it for you after the program terminates, and there is no guarantee that which fd will be flushed first.

Answer (score 4):

In your superclass you print to System.err but in the subclass you print to System.out so your issue has nothing to do with inheritance but on how printing works.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor Name **must** be the same as **class name**, in your case class name is **Bus** and you are typing **bus** in your constructor name.

[You can get more info about Constructor here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-constructor)

And the second thing is understanding the difference between **System.out** and **System.err**.

So, **System.out** is used to provide the output and to print it in a console you use *.println() or print()* or whatever you want to use and whatever your give in the **print** function you will get the result in the console as a **plain text**.

But In **System.err**, it's different, and yes you will be able to use the same *.print()* function with **System.err** but the output you will get is now in the form of error **(in Red color as in Exception Logs)**. So, They're just used for the identification between **custom error message** and **custom debug logs**.

Comment: Thank you. That is the mistake when I put code here. Now it corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Your class name is Bus, in your Constructor should have same name as class name, you are having bus as your constructor name, Change it to Bus.

```
class Bus extends vehicle {

    public bus(int y) {
        super(y);
        System.out.println("Sub param");
    }

    public bus() {
        super(11);
        System.out.println("Sub Class defult");
    }
}
```

And from your main function in test change it to :

```
new Bus();
```

Your example works fine after that.

Comment: Whilst you are correct that the constructor must match the class name, it must simply be a transcription error, since the code must have compiled for OP to get output.

Comment: Thank you. That is the mistake when I put code here. Now it corrected.

Comment: @wthamira please mark answer as accepted if it helped you and it solved your problem. so that other users can also know about the problem :-)